# error de sintaxis, keyword_ensure inesperado, esperando al final de la entrada Ruby And Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Buenas tardes Comunidad, vengo con este problema de Ruby & Rails
Soy un poco novato en el lenguaje y este error me tiene consternado,

El error me sale en la ruta `app/views/bienvenida/index.html.haml:20` suponiendo que el numero es la linea de código, esto es lo que tengo en index:

```
#hello.top-header
  #top.callbacks_container
    %ul#slider4.rslides
      %li
        = image_tag("slide.jpg", :alt => "")
      .caption.text-center
        **.slide-text-info**
          %h1 ! Bienvenidos ¡
          .slide-text-info-btns
          %li
            %a{:href => ""}
              = image_tag("slide.jpg", :alt => "")
              .caption.text-center
                .slide-text-info
                  %h1 Conoce lo más destacado
                  .slide-text-info-btns
          %li
            = image_tag("slide.jpg", :alt => "")
              .caption.text-center
                .slide-text-info
                  %h1 ¿Aun no estas dentro?
                  %a{:href => ""}
                    %h2 ! Unete ¡
                  .slide-text-info-btns
          .clear
```

Lo que esta en negritas es la linea 20 de mi código.

Para agregar mas información sobre el proyecto esto es lo que tengo en Application.hmtl.haml:

```
!!!5
%html
  %head
    %title HOW TO!
    = csrf_meta_tags

    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1", :name => "viewport"}
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}

    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"

    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "jquery.cslider"
    = javascript_include_tag "jquery.flexisel"
    = javascript_include_tag "jquery.min"
    = javascript_include_tag "modernizr.custom.28468"
    = javascript_include_tag "owl.carousel"
    = javascript_include_tag "responsive-nav"
    = javascript_include_tag "responsiveslides.min"

  :javascript
    addEventListener("load", function() { 
      setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); 
      function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); 
    }

  :javascript
    $(function() {
      var pull = $('#pull');
      menu = $('nav ul');
      menuHeight = menu.height();

      $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
      });

      $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();

        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
          menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
      });
    });

  :javascript
    (function ($) {
      $("#slider4").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        pager: true,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("before event fired.");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("after event fired.");
        }
      }(jQuery));
    });

  :javascript
    $(function() {
      $('#da-slider').cslider({
        autoplay    : true,
        bgincrement : 450
      });
    });

  :javascript
    $(function() {
      $('#da-slider1').cslider({
        autoplay    : true,
        bgincrement : 450
      });
    });

  %body
    = yield
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme a editar la pregunta Carlos Muñoz , era mi primero post y al parecer tuve varios errrores.

Comment: Estoy seguro de que se trata de un bug de Haml, relacionado con el que se reporta aquí: https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/857 . Como es el compilador el que se equivoca, no hay mucho que hacer. Cualquier cambio al azar puede solucionarlo (o no). De todas maneras, tus <li> están desalineados. Tal vez al hacer ese cambio (dejarlos bien) el compilador no cometa errores....

Comment: podrías colocar el error tal cual te aparece

Comment: Intenta traducirlo a html y ver si funciona. Si funciona, sabes que hay algun problema con tu haml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para debugear la vista, lo primero que tendrías que hacer es aislar el problema, para lo que tenés que eliminar bloques de código hasta que el problema no esté más, para después ir reintroduciendo las lineas de a poco hasta encontrar dónde está el error.

Por otro lado, hay varias cuestiones que te puedo marcar en el código para ayudarte a evitar este tipo de problemas, ya que una de las causas es tener vistas muy complejas (con mucho código).

1. En el layout (`application.html.haml`) llamás muchos javascript mediante `javascript_include_tag`, eso no es necesario hacerlo así, en general alcanza con utilizar el primero, el resto del javascript se incorpora utilizando el asset pipeline (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

   El resto de los javascript que agregas en el html también podés agregarlos ahí.
2. Si estás empezando, es mejor usar UTF-8, ya que la mayoría de las librerías esperan ese encoding y te podés encontrar problemas difíciles de encontrar (éste puede ser uno, con ese signo de admiración tan cerca). Mirá el encoding de los archivos que uses y cambiá el encoding que declarás en el html.
3. Siempre usá el código más pequeño posible que sea comprensible, fijate que no ganás nada al hacer `= image_tag("slide.jpg", :alt => "")` en vez de hacer `= image_tag "slide.jpg"` y eso agrega ruido que dificulta encontrar errores.

Suerte en la cacería.